# PowerShell with Pester Tests - No test files were found and no scriptblocks were provided

Tags: powershell, pester

Trying to learn Pester (v5.0.4 and PS v7.0.3).  I have these files

**Get-Planet2.ps1**:

```
function Get-Planet ([string]$Name = '*') {
    $planets = @(
        @{ Name = 'Mercury' }
        @{ Name = 'Venus'   }
        @{ Name = 'Earth'   }
        @{ Name = 'Mars'    }
        @{ Name = 'Jupiter' }
        @{ Name = 'Saturn'  }
        @{ Name = 'Uranus'  }
        @{ Name = 'Neptune' }
    ) | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject] $_ }

    $planets | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $Name }
}
```

**Get-Planet2.Tests.ps1:**

```
BeforeAll { 
    # This will bring the function from the main file back to scope.
    . $PSScriptRoot/Get-Planet2.ps1

    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string]$name,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string]$title,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string]$InputFile
    )
}

Describe 'Get-Planet' {
    It 'Given no parameters, it lists all 8 planets' {
        $allPlanets = Get-Planet
        $allPlanets.Count | Should -Be 8
    }

    It 'Earth is the third planet in our Solar System' {
        $allPlanets = Get-Planet
        $allPlanets[2].Name | Should -Be 'Earth'
    }

    It 'Pluto is not part of our Solar System' {
        $allPlanets = Get-Planet
        $plutos = $allPlanets | Where-Object Name -EQ 'Pluto'
        $plutos.Count | Should -Be 0
    }

    It 'Planets have this order: Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune' {
        $allPlanets = Get-Planet
        $planetsInOrder = $allPlanets.Name -join ', ' 
        $planetsInOrder | Should -Be 'Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune'
    } 

}
```

**Call-Get-Planet2.ps1:**

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$path = "$here/Get-Planet2.Tests.ps1"
$parameters = @{name = "John"; title = "Sales"; InputFile = "$here/test.json"}

write-host "Path: $path"
write-host $parameters

Invoke-Pester -Script @{Path=$path;Parameters=$parameters}
```

### **My Problem:**

When I run Call-Get-Planet2.ps1, I ended with the below error.  I can't figure out why it is doing this.  Need guidance.  Thanks

*System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: **No test files were found and no scriptblocks were provided.**
at Invoke-Pester, /Users/myaccount/.local/share/powershell/Modules/Pester/5.0.4/Pester.psm1: line 4520
at , /Users/myaccount/repos/myrepo/Pester/Call-Get-Planet2.ps1: line 8
at , : line 1*

Comment: What studies have you reviewed before diving into this? For example [pester beginning](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=pester+beginning)

Comment: I went thru the Pester tutorial.  My files are mainly from the tutorial.  I made a changes by adding the parameters to the tests.ps1 file.  When I try to add invoke-pester -script (with parameters), it failed with the mentioned error.  Been doing more research, it may be because the the now v5.0.4 is not working well with parameters.

Comment: @UltraGC - Starting from scratch: what happens when you cd into the folder containing the tests file and simply `Invoke-Pester .`?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks for the suggestions.  I get "The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,.." when just running invoke-pester.  I moved the "param" section (in Get-Planet2.Tests.ps1 ) of of before-all section but didn't help much.  In 5.0.4, it could be that the "parameters" is ignored or no longer requred?

Comment: Not sure but I think you need to wrap everything in a function. Can you wrap a `function Get-Planet-Tests {` ... `}` around your testcode?

Comment: They changed how you call Invoke-Pester in version 5. Check out the information about the Configuration object here:

https://github.com/pester/Pester#simple-and-advanced-interface

If you are using a tutorial pre-v5 there are some significant differences so you'll want to read through that. Reply if you run into any other issues and I'll try to help out.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  My tutorial is pre-v5.  Will need to re-visit this when I have more time as other priorities have came up.

Answer (score 1):

***If you encounter this error*** ('No test files were found and no scriptblocks were provided'), you should follow `LievenKeersmaekers'` suggestion (made in the question comments), which is to execute the test file more directly by doing something like the following:

```
cd {TO\A\FOLDER\WITH\A\TEST_FILE}
Invoke-Pester -Path .\{TEST_FILE}.ps1
```

You'll likely see a more descriptive error message that will help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pester v5 had a breaking change and removed support for `Invoke-Pester -Script <hashtable>`. **Pester 5.1** re-introduced support for script parameters using containers which you create with `New-PesterContainer -Path <file> -Data <parametersHashtable>` and invoke using `Invoke-Pester -Container ...`.

For the original demo, upgrade to Pester 5.1 or later and modify:

- Get-Planet2.Tests.ps1 to:

```
# Script parameters need to be in the root of the file.
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string]$name,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string]$title,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string]$InputFile
)

BeforeAll { 
    # This will bring the function from the main file back to scope.
    . $PSScriptRoot/Get-Planet2.ps1
}

Describe 'Get-Planet' {
    It 'Given no parameters, it lists all 8 planets' {
        $allPlanets = Get-Planet
        $allPlanets.Count | Should -Be 8
    }

    It 'Earth is the third planet in our Solar System' {
        $allPlanets = Get-Planet
        $allPlanets[2].Name | Should -Be 'Earth'
    }

    It 'Pluto is not part of our Solar System' {
        $allPlanets = Get-Planet
        $plutos = $allPlanets | Where-Object Name -EQ 'Pluto'
        $plutos.Count | Should -Be 0
    }

    It 'Planets have this order: Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune' {
        $allPlanets = Get-Planet
        $planetsInOrder = $allPlanets.Name -join ', ' 
        $planetsInOrder | Should -Be 'Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune'
    } 

}
```

- Call-Get-Planet2.ps1 to:

```
# $PSScriptRoot is easier than Split-Path :-)
$here = $PSScriptRoot
$path = "$here/Get-Planet2.Tests.ps1"
$parameters = @{name = 'John'; title = 'Sales'; InputFile = "$here/test.json" }

Write-Host "Path: $path"
Write-Host $parameters

# -Script <hashtable> is not supported in v5. 
# Use New-PesterContainer
$container = New-PesterContainer -Path $path -Data $parameters
Invoke-Pester -Container $container
```